# use Jquery to find number assign to row in a table and return entire row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap to create a form and a table that is not being displayed to the front end.

```
<section id="verificar-diploma">
    <div class="container border bg-light border-primary rounded d-flex justify-content-center my-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <label class="h4 my-3" for="code">Entre Codigo</label>
            <input type="text" id="code" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" placeholder="Enter Number">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Verifie</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="students-table" class="d-none">

   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>jdoe@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Will</td>
                <td>Johnson</td>
                <td>will@yahoo.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Shannon</td>
                <td>Williams</td>
                <td>shannon@yahoo.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Is it possible to use jquery to read the input, check if the number exists in the number row and return the rest of the information on that row?

Comment: yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".btn").on("click",function(){

  // Get the input's value
  var value = $(this).prev("input").val();
  
  // Loop through the table to find all scope="row" elements
  $(".table").find("[scope='row']").each(function(){
    // Found the one with the same value as the input
    if($(this).text() == value){
      // Prepare the result
      var result = "";
      // Loop through all td of the row to concat the text
      $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each(function(){
        result += $(this).text()+" ";
      });
      
      // Show result
      alert(result);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>



<section id="verificar-diploma">
    <div class="container border bg-light border-primary rounded d-flex justify-content-center my-3 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <label class="h4 my-3" for="code">Entre Codigo</label>
            <input type="text" id="code" class="form-control form-control-sm mb-3" placeholder="Enter Number">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Verifie</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section id="students-table" class="d-none">

   <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>jdoe@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">2</th>
                <td>Will</td>
                <td>Johnson</td>
                <td>will@yahoo.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">3</th>
                <td>Shannon</td>
                <td>Williams</td>
                <td>shannon@yahoo.com</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It would be a nice idea to overlook the documentation of the methods used here:

[`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/), [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/), [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/), [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/),  [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/),